# Obtaining a list of Cloudfiles with fog - stack level too deep

Tags: ruby, fog

I'm attempting to obtain a list of all files in my Rackspace Cloudfiles account using the "fog" gem (github.com/fog/fog). However, I keep running into a stack level too deep error.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'fog'

RACKSPACE_USERNAME = 'USERNAME'
RACKSPACE_API_KEY = 'API_KEY'

connection_rackspace = Fog::Storage.new({
  :provider           => 'Rackspace',
  :rackspace_username => RACKSPACE_USERNAME,
  :rackspace_api_key  => RACKSPACE_API_KEY
})

connection_rackspace.directories.each do |directory_rackspace|
  directory_rackspace.files.each do |file_rackspace|
    puts file_rackspace.key
  end
end
```

I gather that it has to do with that "each" loop, but can't figure out where to go from here.

Comment: I doubt that the double-each cases a stack overflow. Sound more like a bug in fogs code. Can you provide the (snipped of) stacktrace? I should point to the methods that are behaving badly here.

Comment: gems/fog-1.10.0/lib/fog/core/attributes.rb:63: stack level too deep (SystemStackError) @MarvinFrick

Comment: fwiw, i just tested this and i did not get a stack level too deep error. I'm using the newest release of fog also

Comment: @Eugene - Had an opportunity to test this on another user account - runs perfectly. It must be a permissions issue with my environment. How do I close this question?

Comment: I would suggest opening an issue about it on github, it sounds rather bugish.  Even if it is a permissions issue, there should be a way to handle that exception that doesn't result in the interpreter entering an infinite loop.  My first thoughts is that it could be a directory name that might match a method name, or something similar. You could potentially try using `pry` and work your way through the code block 1 iteration at a time and see which directory/file is causing the stack error.

Comment: @Neil I work on Fog for Rackspace. Can you send me a full stack trace? I would like to figure this one out!

Comment: Appears, this turned out to be an issue with my installation of Ruby. Working with Kyle Rames, I attempted in in Ruby 1.9.3 and Ruby 2.0.0 on various machines and accounts. Finally, on the machine/account combo that wasn't able to run this in Ruby 2.0.0 - I ran `rvm reinstall 2.0.0` and now am having no trouble.